# Computed column in EF Core incorrect mapping

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Trying to use a Computed column in my query but it seems EF Core handles it like any other column and just ignores the mapping. Is there somehting i do wrong here? or do i misunderstand the usage of the computed column :S This is almost the same examples as the documentation are using.

[EF Core documentation](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relational/computed-columns.html)

I am running `MapUsers(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());` inside the OnModelCreating.

Mapping:

```
private static void MapUsers(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entity)
{
    entity.Property(p => p.FullName)
          .HasComputedColumnSql("[FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]");
    entity.ToTable("User");
}
```

this is the generated query:

```
 SELECT [FirstName], [u].[FullName], [u].[LastName]
 FROM [User] AS [u]
```

Managed to get it to work in the query by using this line instead of using a strongly typed property

```
$"{u.FirstName} {u.LastName}".Contains(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same confusion and ended up [asking](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6752) the EF team.

The explanation is that the SQL query you put as parameter is only used for migrations. If you're using database-first or not using migrations at all, that parameter is not used.